# the accuracy of a random baseline

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

Hi everyone I am new in machine learning and deep learning field can someone explaining  to me, **What is the accuracy of a random baseline ?**

Comment: Is this homework? If so please explain what you think or where is your difficulty. Hint: a random baseline predicts the target class randomly, so for example it has 50% chance to predict correctly between 2 outcomes.

Comment: @Erwan If the two outcomes are represented equally

Comment: @Dave thanks for noticing